# Why does Data Flow Sink Cache not have all Data Preview results?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm seeing a significant discrepancy in Data Flow results when using a Cache Sink vs a Data Set Sink.  I recreated a simple example to demonstrate.

I uploaded a simple JSON file to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "id": 456,
      "name": "DEF"
    },
    {
      "id": 789,
      "name": "GHI"
    }
  ]
}
```

I created a simple Data Flow that loads this JSON file, flattens it out, then returns it via a Sink.  I'm primarily interested in using a Cache Sink because the output is small and I will ultimately need the output for the next pipeline step.  (*Write to activity output* is checked.)

[image]

You can see that the Data Preview shows all 3 rows.  (I have two sinks in this example simply because I'm illustrating that these do not match.)

Next, I create a pipeline to run the data flow:

[image]

Now, when I debug it, the Data Flow output only shows 1 record:

```js
        "output": {
            "TestCacheSink": {
                "value": [
                    {
                        "id": 123,
                        "name": "ABC"
                    }
                ],
                "count": 1
            }
        },
```

However, the second Data Set Sink contains all 3 records:

```js
{"id":123,"name":"ABC"}
{"id":456,"name":"DEF"}
{"id":789,"name":"GHI"}
```

I expect that the output from the Cache Sink would also have 3 records.  ***Why is there a discrepancy?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you choose cache as a sink, you will not be allowed to use logging. You see the below error during validation before debug.

[image]

To fix which, when you select "**none**" for logging, it automatically checks "**first row only**" property! This is causing it to write only the first row to cache sink. **You just have to manually uncheck it before running debug.**

Here is how it looks...

[image]